# How do I add a number to a label in C#?

Tags: c#, numbers, label

So I want to have a number that can be added to but then written out in a label. I'm doing it in Visual C#.NET.

For example, if I had code like this (either in a timer or while loop):

```
        int i = 0;
        i = i + 5;

        label4 = "Current Number of Views: " + i.ToString();
```

I can't use ToString() to convert it to a string. So how would I make i displayable

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why can't you use ToString?

Comment: Is it part of a homework challenge to not use ToString?

Comment: -1 - cough, cough `string.Format`

Comment: You don't even need to call `ToString()` since you are concatenating ("adding") it to an existing string, it would be done for you implicitly.

Comment: And you can't set a `Label` equal to a string anyway...

Answer (score 4):

While I don't understand why you can't use `i.toString()`, I suppose that you could also use something like

```
label4.Text = String.Format("Current Number of Views: {0:d}", i);
```

This should yield the same result.

**Edit:** as @BiggsTRC points out (which I didn't think of), your error is probably a result of not assigning to the right variable.  You probably should access the property `label4.Text` to assign to.  The code example fixes this properly now.

Answer (score 3):

u could use String.Format without explicitly using ToString()

```
label4.Text = String.Format("Current Number of Views: {0}", i);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.  The one issue i see is the label itself. It should look like this:

```
label4.Text = "Current Number of Views: " + i.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand why cant you use i.ToString(). By default, i is assigned with 0 value and hence, i.ToString() would not throw any exception.

if you are using WPF , then you should assign the value to the **content property** of the label.

```
label4.Content = "Current Number of Views: " + i.ToString();
```